# Fabric Remote Execution requiring a user response from a prompt?

Tags: python, linux, fabric

I would like to handle when a fabric script requires a response.

Eg. `Apply the above migration? (yes|no) [no]:`

The `fab` function that creates this prompt:

`local("php root/protected/yiic.php migrate")`

Comment: If by "handle" you mean "supply an answer", don't forget the POSIX command `yes`.

Comment: @mdurant Be useful and edit the question rather

Comment: but I really don't know what the question means, I am guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable interactive mode during running command:

```
local("php root/protected/yiic.php migrate --interactive=0")
```

[From docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration#customizing-migration-command):

**interactive**: boolean, specifies whether to perform migrations in an interactive mode. Defaults to true, meaning the user will be prompted when performing a specific migration.